# phpdoc on a mvc project with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpdoc

i developed a project in Codeigniter following the MVC pattern.

That means that , for example, i have a controller called Items , which call a model called Items_model ,which get files from database and finally those those file are passed to a view called Item_view.

Now i need to document it, and im trying to use phpdoc.

My main question is about how to , inside the explanation of a function  in a controller, link the behaviour of that function with a model and the view in a functional way, not just write the names in plain text.
i was reading about packages, but dont know how to use it properly

i hope you can help, im very noob with phpdoc.

thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Sverd.

Answer (score 1):

I think that PHPDoc doesn't support this type of integration with CodeIgniter. Probably you should use PHPDoc and modify manually the documentation created.

Anyways, using CodeIgniter and renaming correctly all the files, you shouldn't have any problem:

```
Controller -> controllers/home.php
Model -> models/home.php
View -> home.php
```

If you specify that you're using CodeIgniter (which uses MVC pattern), the documentation explains by itself.

PS:

One 'googled' link (I haven't read it completely):

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/58302/